# Dynamic Add Input After User Select Files and Button

Tags: jquery

I have a scenario here.

1) I have a photo wrapper, where user will choose the img file from their computer. After the user have chosen the file, it will then display the preview img as well as the photo caption input.

Preview img, delete button and photo caption input is to be display none on page load.

2) After I am done with the 1st step, I will click on the Add Button if I have more images. It will repeat Step 1 exactly the same.

The actual scenario happening now :

If I click on Add Button, it will add 1. But if I click the 2nd time, it will add 2 instead of 1.

Below is my code :

```
<div class="trip-ul-photo">
    <div class="trip-ul-photo-wrapper clearfix">

  <!-- This part 1 is the input file + label + preview img + delete button, preview img and button will display none until user have select their img file from their computer -->
        <div class="trip-ul-photo-group col-lg-12">
            <input id="trip-photo1" type="file" class="" name="trip-photo[]">
            <label for="trip-photo1"></label>
            <img class="pro-set-up-photo-preview" src="" alt="Trip Photo 1" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-photo-del" role="button">X</button>
        </div>
    <!-- End of part 1 -->

    <!-- This part 2 is to generate the photo caption dynamically when the user have select their img file from their computer -->
        <div class="trip-ul-photo-cap-wrapper"></div>
    <!-- End of part 2 -->

    </div>
</div>

<!-- When user clicks on this button, it will add in the Part 1 and Part 2 dynamically -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-trip-ul-photo" role="button">Add Photo +</button>
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/u1j5bdhp/

I am not very good in JS and so my code might be messy.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: i didnt go through your entire code, but at first glance it seems that you are defining `photo_str` outside of the click event handler but are not resetting it before/after you are done with it, and therefore its value remains for the next time you enter the click handler. set `photo_str=""` at the beginning or end of the click event handler. or move its definition inside the handler.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the help!